# How to make jQuery secure from XSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xss, bluemix-app-scan

I have a website that uses jquery and bootstrap.

Now when i run it through a scanning application, a bunch of issues show up including the use of append(), html() and write() and pointing to XSS attacks. These issues are found in bootstrap and jquery files (bootstrap.js).

After a search through stackoverflow i found secure alternatives to these jquery functions but unfortunately these alternatives break my application.

Is there any way for me to resolve the security issues without changing the underlying bootstrap code?

or is it somehow safe as there is no external input to the site and all the files come from a trusted source?

Comment: `Is there any way for me to resolve the security issues without changing the underlying bootstrap code?` There's nothing inherently wrong with any of the libraries you mention - it's all down to how you use them.

Answer (score 0):

> or is it somehow safe as there is no external input to the site and all the files come from a trusted source?

Yes (assuming your trust in the source is not misplaced).

Comment: Would you mind pointing me to a resource that explains this concept?

Comment: @MaazMikail — You want me to find a third party that will also tell you that you can trust things you can trust?

Comment: No not really. The trusted source in this case is my own self. Just wanting to find something to show my PM that this is secure.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) function for unsafe inputs:

```
var input = $("'/><script>alert('I am an attacker!')</script>").text();
```